# Get value only from Position

Tags: matrix, output

If have the following command

```
Position[{a, b, a, a, b, c, b}, b]

(* Out[1]= {{2}, {5}, {7}} *)
```

Is it possible to get only a sequence of values instead of this list, like

```
Out[2]= 2, 5, 7
```

I'm interested in the values only and don't need the list structure.

Comment: Have a look at `Flatten`.

Comment: `Out[2]=2,5,7` is not mathematica syntax. Do you mean `Out[2]={2,5,7}` ?

Comment: Out[2]={2,5,7} is possible? how to do it @andre?

If the output become 2, 5 , 7, how to manipulate it? so it come to be Out[2]=2,5,7?

thanks

Comment: `Out[2]={2,5,7}` is possible and trivial. To do it use `Flatten`, as suggested by @b.gatessucks. The question "How to manipulate it" as so many possible interpretations that I can't answer. Otherwise I don't understand : "so it come to be ..."

Answer (score 11):

The question is, what do you want to do with the output. The output of `Position` is in a form so that it can directly be used with `Extract`

```
list = {a, b, a, a, b, c, b};
pos = Position[list, b];
Extract[list, pos]
(* {b, b, b} *)
```

For this simple example, it is a bit useless because we already know, that on all positions `pos` we have a `b` in `list`. Unfortunately, your simple example covers another thing, which is that you really need the nested structure `{{2}, {5}, {7}}` in non-trivial cases.

If you really just want the values, than I suggest (as the others too) to use `Flatten`

```
Flatten[pos]
(* {2, 5, 7} *)
```

When your input is really just a one-dimensional structure or list, the above can be used with `Part` to extract the values of `list`

```
Part[list, Flatten[pos]]

(* or a bit shorter *)

list[[Flatten[pos]]]
```

In most cases you cannot simply flatten the output and to give you a small non-trivial example let's assume we have a somewhat moderate complex expression

```
 expr = 20 x^3 Cos[x + x^5] - Sin[x + x^5] - 10 x^4 Sin[x + x^5] - 25 x^8 Sin[x + x^5]
```

Now you want to use `Position` to find all positions where `x` appears with an exponent

```
pos = Position[expr, x^_]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 2}} *)
```

What you see is, that the structure is nested and this has a reason: To find the first `x^_` which is at position `{1,2}` you have to select the first part which is

```
20 x^3 Cos[x + x^5]
```

and there the second one. Even more nested it gets, when the search pattern in located inside one of the `Sin`'s. If you flatten this output of `Position` you get nothing useful but feeding the output to `Extract` gives you everything you wanted

```
Extract[expr, pos]

(* {x^3, x^5, x^5, x^4, x^5, x^8, x^5} *)
```

Comment: For the case of a vector, perhaps it is worth adding that his desired output can be used nicely with `Part`. +1

Comment: @Rojo Thanks and your suggestion is now included.